# send drag and drop files manually using "jQuery Form Plugin"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I am a bit stuck here and I need help..
I am trying to make drag and drop file upload in my website, I have started from scratch since I could not find any plugin that will fit my needs.

this is what I have so far:

File Drop detection:

```
var dropzone = document.getElementById('holder');

dropzone.ondragover = function(){
            this.className = 'well pull-left display-ex-pic drag_hover';
            return false;
        }

dropzone.ondragleave = function(){this.className = 'well pull-left display-ex-pic'; return false;}

        dropzone.ondrop = function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            this.className = 'well pull-left display-ex-pic';
            readURLs(e.dataTransfer.files);//display the pictures
            images = e.dataTransfer.files;
            images_obj = e.dataTransfer;
        }
```

submitting the form through AJAX:

```
formImages = new FormData();
var status = $('#status');
$('#image_upload').hide();
$('form').ajaxForm({

    beforeSend: function() {
    $('#image_upload').show();
    $('#math li .mathquill-editable').each(function() {
        a = $('#math-text').val();
        $('#math-text').val(a + $(this).mathquill('latex') + '[{line}]');
    });

    for (var x = 0; x < images.length; x = x + 1) {
        formImages.append(images[x].fileName, images[x]);
    }
    },
    data: {'files[]': formImages},
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        $('#image_upload').attr('aria-valuenow', percentComplete).css('width', percentComplete + '%').html(percentComplete + '%');

    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
        status.html(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Now my problem is that after the user drops the files the files get into a files array using `e.dataTransfer.files` and then I want to submit those files with a progress bar along with all of the form data using the "jQuery Form Plugin" from here http://malsup.com/jquery/form/.

Does anyone know how is it possible to send files using the  "jQuery Form Plugin" manually?

Answer (score 1):

I just happen to found this plugin and it works perfectly in very short time of implementation.

http://www.dropzonejs.com/#installation

Basically:

1. Include the plugin
2. Include the HTML
3. Code your File
4. Receiver at server side ( example included in the URL )
5. Adjust
   CSS.